# How to apply $lt to array elements?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying this (all documents have `tags` array):

```
db.find($lt: ['$tags.0.created', '2019-05-05'])
```

I want to fetch all documents where the first tag was created before the specified date. It doesn't work. I mean, it returns all elements. What's wrong in this query?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `db.find({'tags.0.created': {'$lt': 2019-05-05'}})`?

Comment: @bro-grammer I'm getting `Unrecognized expression '$tags.0.created'`

Comment: I think `$` is redundant. I have edited the comment.

Comment: @bro-grammer now I'm getting `FieldPath field names may not contain '.'`

Comment: @yegor256 I don't think so. Post sample documents and the _exact_ query you're running now. ([mcve]). Versions of the shell/server too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual find would look something like this:

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.find({ 'tags.0.created': { $lt: '2019-05-05' } })
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7oYcW5XOsqS)

Comment: Oh, mongo fiddle, nice. Didn't know about this one.

Comment: @Akrion thanks, the actual problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540710/fieldpath-field-names-may-not-contain-when-trying-to-use-aggregate