# FieldPath field names may not contain '.' when trying to use AGGREGATE

Tags: ruby, mongodb

What's wrong with my query?

```
db.table.aggregate([
  {
    '$match' => {
      '$expr' => {
        '$and' => [
          { '$eq' => [{ '$size' => '$events' }, 4] },
          { 'events.0.updated' => { '$lt' => '2019-05-05' } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I'm getting:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'
```

Comment: This `$lt` here is not the same `$lt` as in `find`. Different syntax: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/#exp._S_lt

Comment: And also should be `$events`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please post an answer with the right syntax?

Comment: If you fix the syntax in the question. No such thing as `=>` in JSON :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's Ruby, not JavaScript

Comment: I see. JS/mongoshell snippet would have been more usable, though (in that playground thingie, for example). Ruby is irrelevant here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query

If you are using [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) then you can easily use aggregation operator inside it. So Instead of using `.dot` notation to find the element, you can use  [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator which provides you the facility to choose the element you want.

```
db.table.aggregate([
  { '$match': {
    '$expr': {
      '$and': [
        { '$eq': [{ '$size': '$events' }, 4] },
        { '$lt': [{ '$arrayElemAt': ['$events.updated', 0] }, '2019-05-05'] }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Or the way you were trying to do

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "events.0.updated": { "$lt": "2019-05-05" },
    "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$events" }, 4] }
  }}
])
```

You can check the [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) behaviour [**here**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions)

Comment: I get `MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$expr'`

Comment: @CodyBugstein kindly update your mongodb version

Comment: I have `4.2.11`